# Advise on index.php page taking to much resources

Tags: magento2, php, code-analysis

Question that I asked the hosting company:

> admin and website is moving to slow again

Reply from them:

> What hosting has stated: [ We have checked and found that the following page is utilizing high CPU and there is something wrong with index.php lsphp:rnb2/public_html/stuffwholesale.com/index.php ]

This is the page at this address:

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `index.php` is main access point of any magento page, so all troubles inside the Magento. If you want to find a real issue you must enable the  built-in magento profiler, and check on any slow page what exactly cause an long loading. Here is an exploration about ["How to enable and use Magento built-in profiler"](https://webkul.com/blog/profiler-in-magento-2/) and here is a [corresponding DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html).

Comment: Thank you I will pass it on to my person and hopefully he can fix. again. thanks